# How do I capitalize all the characters in a string in Rust?

Tags: rust

There's an answer here for how to capitalize the ASCII characters in a string. This is not quite adequate for my specific problem.

Comment: Does it need to be Unicode-savvy? Because in Unicode moving from upper to lower (or vice versa) may depend on the *surrounding characters* which requires converting word by word, instead of character by character, and nearly no language supports out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any function to do it directly, but you can use the functions in the [`UnicodeChar`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc_unicode/str/trait.UnicodeStr.html) trait with `chars` and `map` like:

```
let str = "hello øåÅßç";
let up = str.chars().map(|c| c.to_uppercase()).collect::<String>();
println!("{}", up);
```

Output:

```
HELLO ØÅÅßÇ
```

Tested on `rustc 0.13.0-dev (66601647c 2014-11-27 06:41:17 +0000)`

Comment: I had to change this to `let up = str.chars().flat_map(|c| c.to_uppercase()).collect::<String>();`  for 1.41.0-nightly

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who wanders in off Google, things have improved since Rust 0.13.0. (I'm on Rust 1.13.0)

`&str` (string slice) provides `to_uppercase()` and you can coerce anything to it.

```
// First, with an &str, which any string can coerce to.
let str = "hello øåÅßç";
let up = str.to_uppercase();
println!("{}", up);

// And again with a String
let nonstatic_string = String::from(str);
let up2 = nonstatic_string.to_uppercase();
println!("{}", up2);
// ...if this fails in an edge case, use &nonstatic_string to force coercion
```

Regarding Matthieu M.'s comment, this conversion should be fully Unicode-compliant.

Here's a runnable copy [on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20First%2C%20with%20an%20%26str%2C%20which%20any%20string%20can%20coerce%20to.%0A%20%20%20%20let%20str%20%3D%20%22hello%20%C3%B8%C3%A5%C3%85%C3%9F%C3%A7%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20up%20%3D%20str.to_uppercase()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20up)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20And%20again%20with%20a%20String%0A%20%20%20%20let%20nonstatic_string%20%3D%20String%3A%3Afrom(str)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20up2%20%3D%20nonstatic_string.to_uppercase()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20up2)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...if%20this%20fails%20in%20an%20edge%20case%2C%20use%20%26nonstatic_string%20to%20force%20coercion%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)

In case it helps newcomers to understand what's going on:

1. `String`s implement `Deref<Target=str>`, so you can call any `str` methods on `String`.
2. `str::to_uppercase()` takes `&str` (a borrowed, non-mutable slice. In other words, a read-only reference to a string), so it'll accept pretty much anything.
3. `str::to_uppercase()` allocates a new `String` and returns it, so its return value isn't constrained by the borrowing rules for the input.

The caveat mentioned in the comment at the end is that, if you call `my_string.to_uppercase()` as `str::to_uppercase(my_string)`, then it'll complain like this:

```
expected &str, found struct `std::string::String`
```

What's happening is that `my_string.to_uppercase()` isn't actually equivalent to that... it's equivalent to `str::to_uppercase(&my_string)`.

(You can't auto-deref if you're not starting with a reference. You don't need to provide the `&` when making a method call because the `&self` in the method definition does it for you.)